# TextField de mi pantalla login es 'tapado' cuando se habilita el teclado

Tags: flutter, dart

Como puedo hacer para lograr este efecto de que no se vea afectado mi textField y los otros botones al escribir?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que uso de ejemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF954CFB),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 64.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Inicia sesión',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 32,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: inputDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: 'Correo',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: inputDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: 'Contraseña',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 64.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Cancelar',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Iniciar Sesión',
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const InputDecoration inputDecoration = InputDecoration(
  enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  ),
  filled: true,
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  ),
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white70,
  ),
  fillColor: Color(0xFFB88CFF),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu widget `Column` agrégale un `SingleChildScrolView` como parent para que pueda estirarse y no afecte la pantalla.

Te recomiendo nuestro [canal sobre Flutter en español](https://youtu.be/z6Okn25AmEo?t=170), *The Dart Side*, donde tocamos de todo un poco acerca de Flutter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el ejemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {

  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(36, 43, 47, 1),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 43.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(    // new line
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildFirstName(),
                    _buildLastName(),
                    _buildEmail(),
                    _buildPassword(),
                    _buildConfirmPassword(),
                    _buildSignUpButton(context)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }


  Widget _buildFirstName() {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: (value) =>
      value.isEmpty ? "First name cannot be empty" : null,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1), fontFamily: 'RadikalLight'),
      decoration:
      _buildInputDecoration("First name", 'assets/ic_worker.png'),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLastName() {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
        child: TextFormField(
          validator: (value) =>
          value.isEmpty ? "Last name cannot be empty" : null,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1), fontFamily: 'RadikalLight'),
          decoration: _buildInputDecoration("Last name", ''),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildEmail() {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: (value) => !isEmail(value) ? "Sorry, we do not recognize this email address" : null,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1), fontFamily: 'RadikalLight'),
      decoration: _buildInputDecoration("Email", 'assets/ic_email.png'),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPassword() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _passwordController,
      validator: (value) =>
      value.length <= 6 ? "Password must be 6 or more characters in length" : null,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1), fontFamily: 'RadikalLight'),
      decoration:
      _buildInputDecoration("Password", 'assets/ic_password.png'),
    );
  }
  bool isEmail(String value) {
    String regex =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(regex);

    return value.isNotEmpty && regExp.hasMatch(value);
  }

  Widget _buildConfirmPassword() {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
        child: TextFormField(
          obscureText: true,
          validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ||
              (value.isNotEmpty && value != _passwordController.text)
              ? "Must match the previous entry"
              : null,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1), fontFamily: 'RadikalLight'),
          decoration: _buildInputDecoration("Confirm password", ''),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildSignUpButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 43.0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.62,
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: const Text(
          "Sign Up",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 48, 52, 1),
              fontFamily: 'RadikalMedium',
              fontSize: 14),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 4.0,
        onPressed: () {
//          _validateAndSubmit();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

InputDecoration _buildInputDecoration(String hint, String iconPath) {
  return InputDecoration(
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1))),
      hintText: hint,
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(151, 151, 151, 1))),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(252, 252, 252, 1)),
      icon: iconPath != '' ? Image.asset(iconPath) : null,
      errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(248, 218, 87, 1)),
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color:  Color.fromRGBO(248, 218, 87, 1))),
      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color:  Color.fromRGBO(248, 218, 87, 1))));
}
```

fuente: https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso no hacía scaffold porque tenía `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` en `false`, o sea estaba así:

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: getAppBar(context),
      body: getBody(),
 );
```

Comment: Explica el porque de tu respuesta y como es que resuelve la pregunta, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por [ask] y por [tour] para que comprendas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, de paso ganas tus primeras medallas.